# e.target.value onChange input react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have this simple onChange function, but I have problem. When I change my input first time and for example enter "1" my variable `inputOne` is returns empty string:

```
const [inputOne, setInputOne] = useState('');
const onChange = (e) => {
 setInputOne(e.target.value);

  console.log(e.target.value); // first changing of input returns 1
  console.log(inputOne); // first changing of input returns EMPTY string

}
   <div className="container">
          <input type="number" name='input1' value={inputOne} onChange={onChange} />
   </div>
```

but when I change this input again and add one more "1"(in total 11) my console is:

```
console.log(e.target.value); // returns 11
console.log(inputOne); // returns 1
```

Why it's happening with my variable `inputOne`?

New code:

```
const [inputOne, setInputOne] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
 console.log(inputOne);
}, [inputOne])

const onChange = (e) => {

  setInputOne(e.target.value);
  console.log(e.target.value);
  setTimeout(() => { 
  
  if(e.target.value){
  const filteredpost = posts[0].filter(mfo => mfo.minPrice <= Number(inputOne));
  setPostsToShow(filteredpost.slice(0, 20));
  setPost(filteredpost);
  }else{
    const filteredpost = posts[0];
    setPostsToShow(filteredpost.slice(0, 20));
    setPost(filteredpost);
  }}, 1000);
}
```

Comment: why is that surprising? it seems the `onChange` function needs to complete first before the component reactively reruns, and only at the point the change you just made will be reflected in the variable. Until then it still has the old value (`''` at first, and then `'1'`)

Comment: no, this onChange function is completed and 2 the same value return different results. it looks like delay with one symbol for my variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setState is an async function.

In your case, setInputOne queues the change and returns a Promise,
that will not be resolved until the next tick (or even later, if reacts thinks it is worth it to gain some performance).

So the timeline is like this:

- Type into input
- Trigger onChange
- setInputOne (queue the change)
- console.log (the value that is queued)
- console.log (the variable that is queued)
- next tick and consequently the change of the variable.

You can see this with the useEffect hook:

```
useEffect(() => {

console.log(`tell me when inputOne changes`);

}, [inputOne])
```

**UPDATE**

inputOne will never be your updated value inside the onChange function. The onChange function stores the last value until re-render.

Pass your setTimeout to the `useEffect` *OR* change inputOne to `e.target.value` since they will always be the same.

Comment: Thanks! Console log is working for me correctly now. But I should use my variable "inputOne" inside my onChange function, I updated question and added my full function, please check.

Comment: Are you using setTimeout because you are waiting for the inputOne value to change, or are you using it because you actually need it?

Comment: it needs for me. I do filtering and I need delay 1 sec for good UX.

Comment: yes, I can use e.target.value, but if I will have 3 inputs with different values, how I can use the same onchange function?

Comment: What do you mean? Do they need to exchange information or are they independent?

Comment: they are not independent(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230985/discussion-between---and-rodolfo-rangel).

Answer (score 2):

State update in Reactjs is an asynchronous process, therefore it won't be reflected immediately in the next line due to it's asynchronous nature.

If you want to monitor the state whenever its updated, you can use useEffect hook, and place inside its the dependency array the piece of state you want to track.

In your case:

```
useEffect(() => {
 console.log(inputOne);
}, [inputOne])
```

This will be triggered, every time inputOne changes. If you want to use the value from the inputOne to call another function you should implement that logic inside the useEffect, instead of doing it inside the function onChange which updates the inputOne state.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(inputOne){
        const filteredpost = posts[0].filter(mfo => mfo.minPrice <= Number(inputOne));
        setPostsToShow(filteredpost.slice(0, 20));
        setPost(filteredpost);
     }
        else
     {
          const filteredpost = posts[0];
          setPostsToShow(filteredpost.slice(0, 20));
          setPost(filteredpost);
    }
}, [inputOne]);
```

Get rid of the timeout. It's unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks! Console log is working for me correctly now. But I should use my variable "inputOne" inside my onChange function, I updated question and added my full function, please check.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: hmm, thanks. but how should look my input then?